# Is there a German word to describe sentence parts which are delimited by commas?

Tags: single-word-request, terminology, comma

Is there a general word to describe a sentence part, such as a relative clause, but also an infinitive clause?

---

Gibt es ein allgemeines Wort, um Satzteile – zum Beispiel einen Relativsatz, aber auch einen erweiterten Infinitiv – zu beschreiben?

Comment: Do you mean _one_ word to describe them _both_, or _one_ word that describes the _group_ of sentences they belong to?

Comment: Should the word also describe "um Satzteil" in your translation?

Comment: @ApoY2: Is there a difference?

Comment: @Tim: not really, it should reather both describe part of the sentence that would make more or less sense when taken outside of its context.

Comment: @Eldros: It would be useful if you added some examples of what you want the word to describe, as there are other word combinations than relative and infinitive clauses thar are delimited by commas.

Comment: @Eldros: Yes ther certainly is. A word that describes both doesn't exist. The one is a relative clause, the other is an infinitive clause. A word that describes the group they belong in on the other hand, exists: Nebensatz/Teilsatz.

Comment: @ApoY2k: I still don't see any difference. I could say that "they are both _Nebensatz" for example. But I'm afraid we are slowly going into semantics.

Comment: @Eldros: That's right, but you couldn't answer "Nebensatz" if I asked you, what kind of Nebensatz it is. Nebensatz is the group, the actual "thing" is either relative or infinitive.

Comment: @Tom: well I could narrow the definition so: a sentence part, delimited by commas, centered around a verb and making sense. I would have added that they should have a subject, but infinitive clause doesn't have any, although I think it is implied.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only word that comes to my mind is `Teilsatz`.

[Wikipedia (de)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teilsatz):

> Unter **Teilsatz** versteht man jede Wortfolge innerhalb eines Satzes, in dem neben einem Hauptsatz entweder mindestens ein weiterer Hauptsatz oder ein Nebensatz enthalten ist. Jeder dieser Teile, „Hauptsatz“ und „Hauptsatz“ oder „Hauptsatz“ und „Nebensatz“, ist für den gesamten Satz ein Teilsatz. Selbstverständlich können in einem Satz auch mehr Haupt- oder Nebensätze enthalten sein.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. You can use "Nebensatz", but that wouldn't be correct for  infinitive clauses. It might still be understood, though.